# Senior people die for probability

Tags: probability-theory

This problem was invented by Daniel Bernoulli in 1778. So, imagine we have $n$ couples of senior people. $m$ people die. Consider all deaths as equiprobable and calculate the expected value of couples where both partners are alive. Any hints?

Comment: Any thoughts?  Indicator variables are often a good way to address expectation issues.

Answer (score 3):

Hint: expected value is linear.  The expected number of surviving couples is $n$ times the probability of a given couple surviving.

Answer (score -1):

I will be sincery, I am not very sure about how to calculate this, but with my brother we develop this idea to calculate the death chance:
$$\frac{m}{2n} \times \frac{m-1}{2n-1}$$
Imagine this:

```
We have 10 persons, 5 couples, 5 deaths:
The chance of a husband to die is:
     deaths / persons = 50%
The chance of a wife to die is:
     deaths / persons = 50%
But the chance of one of both die, and then the another is:
     one_of_both_death * the_another_of_both_death= (deaths / persons) * (deaths - 1) / (persons - 1) = 22.22%
```

To calculate the survival chance we develop this two ideas:

$$1-(\frac{m}{2n} \times \frac{m-1}{2n-1})$$

Imagine this (simplified):

```
We have 10 persons, 3 die:
The chance of die is:
    deaths / persons = 33.33%
The chance of survive is:
    1 - chance_of_die = 1 - (deaths / persons) = 1 - 0.3333 = 66.66%
```

Or maybe it's the chance of survive one, multiplied the chance of survive the another, so:

$$(1-\frac{m}{2n}) \times (1-\frac{m-1}{2n-1})$$

Comment: The formula that you think is wrong is actually correct for the probability that the husband and wife both die. But (as Robert Israel has hinted) you need the probability that both survive.